# "At the flicks" - where did this term come from?

Tags: word-choice, etymology

How did the term "flicks" come to relate to "movies" or "cinema"? Where did "flicks" come from?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [flickering appearance](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=flick)  of early movies.

> As slang for "film," it is first attested **1926**, a back-formation from *flicker* (v.), from their flickering appearance.
>
> Etymonline

Comment: Yes. Early slang for a movie (which is itself a shortening of "moving picture") was a "flicker-show", because early film projectors had a rather large advance time between frames, in which a shutter obstructs the light source.